# android studio 3.0 sdk folder missing

Tags: android, sdk, directory

I ended up installing Android studio and when I open it, it pops up a window "specify android SDK path", but the android sdk folder in the path

> %LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\sdk

doesn't exist, I tried downloading the installer several times with the same results.